# Choosing parameter ranges for classification problems

Tags: classification, predictive-models, hyperparameter

How do I choose good values of my `param_grid` in `GridSearchCV()`? I see many different methods, but wonder if there is some theory behind choosing reasonable values for the model parameters, so that I don't waste computational power by choosing too many alternatives in my hyperparameter tuning.

The primary goal is to predict well on classification problems, using for example KNN, random forest, decision trees and SVM.

Comment: No: see the no free lunch theorem. But in a particular domain, you will aquire some experience.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question, that each newbie in the field of machine learning/tuning will pose himself. I am working on a paper that tries to answer this question for some of the most well known ML algorithms (elastic net, knn, decision tree, svm, random forest or xgboost). As the paper will be only published next week on arxiv, currently I can only recommend you to have a look at [mlrHyperopt](https://github.com/jakob-r/mlrHyperopt) in R, there are some predefined tuning spaces.

Comment: The paper is now available here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09596